# What would be a word to mean all authorized users?

Tags: word-choice

We manufacture an identification system. A frequent question we get is "How do we use this at our back gates which are for residents only?" Or "....which are for employees only."

In conversation on the phone or at trade shows its easy to explain, but I need something concise that encompasses both residents, employees, and all other authorized users to use in our brochure, website, and other marketing materials.

For a very concrete example we can say I'm working on a FAQ for our company's website. Saying "How can I use this at an authorized only entry?" Doesn't quite sound or convey the same message as "employees only" or "residents only." Is there a better option than Authorized Only which is concise and would include residential and commercial applications?

Comment: This question calls for more concise explanation and better articulation. I am a little at a loss as to what it is all about. For that reason I am down-voting it.

Comment: @WS2 I just edited it for you to be more concise.

Comment: I think you probably are looking for a word such as *off-limits* or *restricted* .

Comment: @DamkerngT. Those don't distinguish betweeen a restricted entrance that has a visitor system in place and a restricted entrance that doesn't. A main gate for example with a guardhouse is restricted but visitors check in with the guard. A restricted entrance on a far back entrance might be only for authorized users which is my dilemma.

Comment: Once they have become a member, they will know that, and to a non member they don't have to know what members do.

Comment: @Tim I don't follow what your comment means.

Comment: dont worry :) my mistake.

Comment: You probably can't say what physical kind of identification you use, but maybe "passholder-only" or "permit-only" might work?

Comment: ooh those might actually. If you leave that as an answer it could be the best I'll find @UlrichSchwarz

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to de-emphasize the person, you could talk about "permit-only"; if your authentification is a physical token of some kind, "passholder" might work. ("Tokenholder" itself might be too technical or suggest that it's used up in the process, like a subway token or a nonce.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just be explicit. "No visitors this entrance" or "All visitors report to main entrance"

Comment: Thanks, if I was the property manager putting up a sign it would work. We manufacture a product for said entrances which needs to be discussed in our marketing materials as I tried to indicate in the examples at the end of the question. (Sorry if you read this before edit, was a bit harsh because of other things. My apologies)

Answer (score 0):

Use "restricted access.*
"How can I use this at an entry with restricted access?"

Comment: Thank you but as said in comment to Damkerng earlier that doesn't distinguish between a restricted access that has a visitor system in place and one that does not. See my 2nd comment on the original question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

"How do we use this at gates which are key/credential/passholders only?"

Whatever authentication/access token you're using, describe it in that term, rather than than *who*. Also, *non-public*.